# Are the Fourier transform non-radiation conditions of Pearle and Haus identical?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform

Are the Fourier transform non-radiation conditions of Pearle and Haus identical?

Philip Pearle published in chapter 7 *Classical Electron Models* of the 1982 book *Electromagnetism* edited by Doris Teplitz, a Fourier Transform approach to Goedecke's earlier non-radiation condition culminating in equation (6.16):
[image]
This appears to originate with Pearle (there being no cite).

Then in 1986, H. A. Haus in "On the radiation from point charges" (Am. J. Phys. 54 (12)) we have equation (13) providing another approach to the non-radiation condition using the Fourier Transform:
[image]
[image]